# Converting numpy array into dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

How do I convert a numpy array into a dataframe column. Let's say I have created an empty dataframe, `df`, and I loop through code to create 5 numpy arrays. Each iteration of my for loop, I want to convert the numpy array I have created in that iteration into a column in my dataframe. Just to clarify, I do not want to create a new dataframe every iteration of my loop, I only want to add a column to the existing one. The code I have below is sketchy and not syntactically correct, but illustrates my point.

```
df = pd.dataframe()
for i in range(5):
   arr = create_numpy_arr(blah) # creates a numpy array
   df[i] = # convert arr to df column
```

Answer (score 26):

This is the simplest way:

```
df['column_name']=pd.Series(arr)
```

Answer (score 8):

Since you want to create a column and not an entire `DataFrame` from your array, you could do

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

column_series = pd.Series(np.array([0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

To assign that column to an existing `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.assign(column_name=column_series)
```

The above will add a column named `column_name` into `df`.

If, instead, you don't have any `DataFrame` to assign those values to, you can pass a `dict` to the constructor to create a named column from your `numpy` array:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'column_name': np.array([0, 1, 2, 3]) })
```

Answer (score 1):

That will work

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(5):
    arr = np.random.rand(10)
    df[i] = arr
```

Maybe a simpler way is to use the vectorization

```
arr = np.random.rand(10, 5)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way if you have a 2d array:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.matrix.transpose(array))
```